# Change the mouse cursor position in fullscreen

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, fullscreen

I am trying to change the mouse position programmatically, in PyGame, using its mouse API:

```
from pygame import mouse
mouse.set_pos(0, 0)
```

This seems to work fine in windowed mode, but in fullscreen mode, nothing happens. I've tried forcefully making the cursor invisible then showing it again, in vain hope that it would reset the thing, but no luck.

---

**EDIT** In the interest of full disclosure, I'm not using PyGame directly. I'm using [OpenSesame](http://osdoc.cogsci.nl/), with its "Legacy" backend (which is essentially a wrapper over PyGame). However, I *do* have access to PyGame primitives, if needs be.

Comment: Did you try a print event to see if its outside the window in full screen mode
           print pygame.mouse.get_pos()

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#comment_pygame_mouse_get_pos

Test with a print to see if 0,0 coords are on the screen

Python 2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
   pygame.init()
   pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
   pygame.display.set_caption('Testing')
   running = True
   while running:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
         if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #print event.button
           print pygame.mouse.get_pos()
   pygame.display.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Python 3.4

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
   pygame.init()
   pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
   pygame.display.set_caption('Testing')
   running = True
   while running:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
         if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #print event.button
           print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
   pygame.display.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Rather than using PyGame directly, I'm using a wrapper framework, of sorts. (So please bear with me!) I printed the result of `get_pos` immediately before and after I attempt to `set_pos`: It is *reporting* the new position correctly (I actually set it to the centre of the screen, rather than `(0, 0)`), but the actual cursor remains static!

Comment: I am not sure then, I had a issue that it was off screen... you could try                                                                                        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)                                                                                                                                                                        this page might help you  [Python Code Examples for pygame.FULLSCREEN](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/7475/pygame.FULLSCREEN)

Comment: This is being done by the framework. Looking through their code, it's doing `set_mode(res, pygame.FULLSCREEN)`, where `res` is set to the resolution I've requested (in my case `(1366, 768)`).